# What kind of algorithm to use

Tags: decision-trees, recommender-system

For a course term project, we have to build a machine learning algorithm in which the user fills out the form and the algorithm analyses the best suitable university based on the responses. I am new in the field of machine learning, and I do not know what kind of algorithm we can use. Is the recommendation system the right approach for this?

I did some reviews on the internet for some similar projects, however, still can not find a good resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many classification algorithms that might be suitable, try XGBoost and best of luck.